# How to make 2 Listbox binds with the same function, without running the same function twice for two lisboxes while selecting another listbox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I have this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
def onselect(event):
    print(event.widget)
root=tk.Tk()
Listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
Listbox2 = tk.Listbox(root)
Listbox.pack(anchor='e', fill='both', expand=True)
Listbox2.pack(anchor='e', fill='both', expand=True)
Listbox.insert('end', 'hello')
Listbox.insert('end', 'bay')
Listbox2.insert('end', 'yes')
Listbox2.insert('end', 'no')
Listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)
Listbox2.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)
```

When I select for example any element from the first listbox I get:

```
.!listbox
```

But then if I try to select the second listbox I get:

```
.!listbox2
.!listbox
```

But I need to get only the second listbox, why is it getting the second and then the first?
How can I fix this?
I need to know what widget I am selecting (it would be better if it could give me the number of the widget: the first listbox 0 the second 1 and so on if more are created).

Answer (score 0):

When you bind to `<<ListboxSelect>>`, your callback will get called once when the old selection is lost, and a second time when the new selection is made. The event is documented to fire when the selection *changes*, not just when it is *set*, and going from the selected state to an unselected state is considered a change.

Here's what's happening:

1. You select from the first listbox, there is no current selection so your callback is called once.
2. You select from the second listbox. Since you didn't set `exportselection=False`, you can only have one thing selected at a time. Therefore your callback will get called for the first listbox when the first listbox loses the selection, and then get called again for the second listbox when the second listbox gets the selection.

> I need to know what widget I am selecting

You are given a reference to a widget. You first need to get the selection from that widget. If the selection is empty then it's safe to assume the callback was called because the item was deselected. If the selection is not empty, you can assume that the callback was because the item was selected.

If you want to be able to have something selected from both widgeta, set `exportselection` to `False` on both listboxes. Then, when you select something in the second, your callback will only be called once since the other listbox won't lose the selection.

Comment: Yes, it works, but now I have one item selected in the first listbox and one in the second. Can I somehow deselect the previous item without getting the function called or not getting a callback when the item was deselected and the exportselection is set to True?

Comment: Or, is it possible to ignore the deselect callback?

Comment: I see only one solution, use the <Button-1> bind

Comment: @IgorDragushhak: If you have a binding on `<<ListboxSelect>>`, by definition it will be called whenever the selection changes. Removing the selection is a change. As I stated in my answer, you can easily ignore the deselect case -- just check to see if anything is selected. If it's not, then the event fired because of a deselection.